# Could a HomePlug be used to connect 2 routers?

Tags: networking

I have 2 routers that I would like to connect together (they are wireless but dont have an AP mode) could I simply buy a pair of homeplugs and connect them in order for all machines to have complete visibility of each other?!

The DHCP will only be enabled on one, so the other will simply be acting as a switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, think of HomePlug adapters as super long ethernet cables.